# Switch between mobile and desktop version

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, mobile

As mentioned in the title i want to know if it is possible to switch from mobile version of a theme to desktop version but without having a separate theme for mobile devices. And to be more specific i mean like there is a button to change from mobile to desktop version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you looking for is a theme with "responsive design", which means the theme will change depending on the size of the screen.

If you google responsive design you will get some examples of it.  There are alot of themes you get for magento that are responsive, but converting an existing custom theme to a responsive layout can be expensive

**Updated due to original question being changed**

If you do have a responsive design then you could use something like this:

http://filzhut.net/projects/responsive-switch/

Comment: my theme is already a responsive one, that's why i stated my question, i don't know how to do it..

Comment: That would be a part of the responsive design theme, if you want to eg remove/change certain things for mobile view that has to be coded in the responsive theme.

Comment: i edited my question i want to be able to change from mobile to desktop version by pressing a button.

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Please check this Following URL

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/theme-switcher-in-magento.html

Comment: What i need is to manually change from mobile version to desktop and the certain module does not do what i want..

Answer (score 0):

What are the differences between your "mobile" site and your "desktop" site?
Is the content different?
One solution could be to create a separate site to be your "mobile" site and name it m.yourwebsite.com or whatever. Then on your homepage your buttons to switch between the two would just be hyperlinks connecting yourwebsite.com to m.yourwebsite.com and vice versa.
Is this what you're going for?